# Коррелят: обязательность, факультативность, возможность

Tags: коррелят

Если кто умрет, я тебя рядом закопаю.

Коррелят: возможность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коррелят не является обязательным для СПП расчлененной структуры, то есть он факультативен, это относится и СПП со значением условия.

Коррелят в условных придаточных - это часть сложного союза (простой союз + предложное сочетание), например:

В том случае если кто умрет, я тебя рядом закопаю.

Я тебя рядом закопаю в том случае, если кто умрет.

Comment: Сейчас прочитала в учебнике, что коррелят невозможен при препозиции. Здесь же придаточная часть перед главной.
Получается: не возможен

Comment: Тут, наверное, такая история. По определению, коррелят должен находиться в главной части, поэтому  "в том случае если" является сложным союзом, если он не расчленяется (коррелят  входит в состав союза и находится в придаточной части). Расчленение союза факультативно, в препозиции придаточного он чаще не расчленяется, но может и расчленяться: "В том случае,  если кто умрет, я тебя рядом закопаю".  И вопрос: "в том случае" - это коррелят?

Comment: Вы очень умная :)

Comment: Анна,  я не очень представляю себе, кого мы сейчас называем умными людьми.  Мне кажется, что  ум в настоящее время превратился в  умение достаточно быстро работать с информацией, применять ее на практике. И  общество  не слишком высоко ценит чисто мыслительные способности людей: "Умный человек, но ничего так и не смог путного в жизни сделать, как-то всё больше слова говорил".

Comment: Это не лишено!..